# how to check getParameter is set in the project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am analayising the existing project, in one of the JSP page I saw that

```
String server=request.getParameter("server");
```

But I am trying to check How I can find where is this server parameter is set

I searched for `setParameter("server")`, no luck
can any one suggest on this

Main idea, I need to change the values for the values which is set in "server" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can look in any of HTML elements, where they may have tag like `<input type='text' id='server' name='server' />` like that. I have given example of text box, it can be anything. 
And no, there is no such method called `request.setParameter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can get this attribute from the html/jsp page from where the **form** is being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

It is set by the HTTP request that was generated by the client side (such as a browser). For example, an HTML form, upon submission, would result in an HTTP request with parameters for each field. A standalone client (non-browser) can set request parameters by merely adding those parameters to the URL itself.

Therefore, first you have to determine what is generating the HTTP request that results in your JSP page being called. Once you find who's generating the request, it will be very easy for you to find how the parameter itself is set.

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.xml` first check, from which form present in JSP/HTML the `request` is coming.

In the corresponding action, you will get all the input fields in the form, which will be fetched in the servelet through `request.getParameter('')`

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is set when any **form is submitted**. Check the **page which calls this servlet**. That page will contain a form having field like `<input type='text' name='server' />`. If not found then check `URL query parameter`.

### EDIT

In `web.xml` check which URL is being mapped to your servlet.

Comment: did you know which page is calling this servlet?

Comment: I have the following entry in my jsp page <b>Server:</b> <select id="server" name="server" class="body">
         <option value="">Select An Environment</option>         
         </select>
         </span>

Comment: In web.xml check which URL is being mapped to your servlet. From that URL you will know the specific page.

Comment: @imrantariq : this seems to be the maual or developers way to go thru the code , find out the related html page and check whether the parameter is submitted from the page or not , right ?? this i know already , thanks fr your help though , i was thinking say you a servlet on a server and a html page sends the request , can we check there if the request is having the parameter with that name or not

Comment: yes you can check that. if(request.getParameter("server") != null){}